# Weight distribution on sliding or “pocket” doors

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, materials

Does anyone know if hollow sliding/pocket doors have a weight/more dense wood at the bottom of the door to prevent from swinging?

Comment: Some have guides or rollers.

Comment: Do some also have heavier weight distributed at the bottom of the door or would that not serve much purpose?

Comment: Take the door off and find the balance point. You will soon know.

Answer (score 2):

It won't help prevent swinging, and in all likelihood would keep the door swinging longer after an impulse force is applied.
As the comments suggest, most inside doors have a guide on the floor (usually in the retracted region, not the doorframe itself).

If you have a barn-door-type sliding door, there may well be a guide/stabilizer near the top of the door.

Answer (score 0):

**They do not**.  No one is really that concerned about it, and weight doesn't stop things from swinging, it just increases the period of the swing.